# Beginner: Faces unable to subdivide

Tags: faces

Hi I am currently starting out blender and i have created a face using vertices.
 I filled the face and now i want to subdivide it.
 However, the subdivision tool does not work on any of the faces. 
Can anyone explain to me how to subdivide the faces and why subdivide works on primitives such as cubes but not on the created face? 
Thank you 
[image: [1]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subdivide tool in Blender [<kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide] mainly works on edges, but in a few special cases including the cases of triangles and quadrangles, it will also work on a face. However, the subdivide tool will not work on the class of faces called N-gons. To subdivide an N-gon either  manually divide the face into quadrangles and triangles, or enter edge select mode, and divide the edges around the face and subdivide the edges.

Comment: Can you explain how to "manually divide the face into quadrangles and triangles, or enter edge select mode, and divide the edges around the face and subdivide the edges"? My question was closed because considered "duplicate" (subdividing a plane with rounded corners) but this answer does not bring an answer. I've manually divided an edge and then filled the gap between them with a line but that doesn't create a selectable face