# Can I subdivide a rectangle with rounded corners?

Tags: modeling, faces

I created a new plane and applied its scale.

I selected the 4 corner vertices and using the `SHIFT + CTRL + B` shortcut, I made the corners of the plane round.

[image]

Now I would like to subdivide this plane a lot like this:

[image]

But when I try to subdivide the plane in Edit mode, the plane does not subdivide.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44693/beginner-faces-unable-to-subdivide https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66063/subdividing-a-simple-plane-does-not-work https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164019/why-cant-i-subdivide https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124678/subdivide-problem

Comment: The extra vertices you added made the plane into an n-gon (face with more than 4 vertices). Blender prefers to work in quads, so it;s best that you avoid n-gon's. Connect the new vertices to their "opposites" before subdividing.

Comment: Take a new primitive plane and subdivide it a *medium* amount, almost like the bottom picture, and then use a subdivision surface modifier.  Apply it if needed.

Comment: Even when I subdivide the rounded corners, it doesn't give the faces I create a center point and they cannot be selected... why? https://imgur.com/a/9GSus5y

Comment: @AllenSimpson I need a rounded corners plane which is very subdivided to make a pool. Crazy just how difficult something simple like this is

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/JkLgG5J

Comment: @AllenSimpson thanks Allen! That’s a much better answer than I’ve gotten so far